# How can I tweak the kv file so my Kivy app occupies half of an Android phone?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

Here's a simplified version of a Kivy app which uses the full smartphone screen. The app has an input field at the top in which you enter commands. Each command is simply output to the output zone as well as added to a command history list. A button enables the user to replay all the commands stored in the list.

My question is: how do I modify the kv file so the app takes only half of the smartphone screen height ? And how can I do that programmatically ?

kv file

```
# ---------- mysimplegui.kv  ----------

#: import main cryptopricergui
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#: import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect


MySimpleGui:

<MySimpleGui>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    requestInput: request
    requestList: requestListView
    resultOutput: readOnlyLog
    toggleHistoButton: toggleHistoryBtn
    replayAllButton: replayAllBtn

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "28dp"

        TextInput:
            id: request
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            foreground_color: 1,1,1,1
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            #ENTER triggers root.submitRequest()
            on_text_validate: root.submitRequest()

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "28dp"
        ToggleButton:
            id: toggleHistoryBtn
            text: "History"
            size_hint_x: 15
            disabled:True
            on_press: root.toggleRequestList()
        Button:
            id: replayAllBtn
            text: "Replay All"
            size_hint_x: 15
            disabled: True
            on_press: root.replayAllRequests()


    # Define starting data and point to the ListItemButton
    # in the Python code
    ListView:
        id: requestListView
        adapter: ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.RequestListButton, args_converter=lambda row_index,rec: {'text':rec, 'on_press':root.historyItemSelected,'size_hint_y': None,'height': 130})
        height: '0dp'
        size_hint_y: None
        on_parent: self.container.parent.effect_cls = ScrollEffect #prevents overscrolling

    ScrollView:
        id: scrlv
        size_hint: (1, 1)
        effect_cls: ScrollEffect #prevents overscrolling
        TextInput:
            id: readOnlyLog
            size_hint: (1, None)
            height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height) #required to enable scrolling when list starts to grow
            readonly: True
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            foreground_color: 1,1,1,1
```

python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton


class RequestListButton(ListItemButton):
    pass


class MySimpleGui(BoxLayout):
    requestInput = ObjectProperty()
    requestList = ObjectProperty()
    resultOutput = ObjectProperty()
    showRequestList = False

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MySimpleGui, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def toggleRequestList(self):
        '''
        called by 'History' toggle button to toggle the display of the history
        command list.
        '''
        if self.showRequestList:
            self.requestList.size_hint_y = None
            self.requestList.height = '0dp'
            self.showRequestList = False
        else:
            self.requestList.height = '100dp'
            self.showRequestList = True

            # Reset the ListView
            self.requestList.adapter.data.extend(
                [])  # improves list view display, but only after user scrolled manually !
            self.resetListViewScrollToEnd(self.requestList)

            self.refocusOnrequestInput()

    def submitRequest(self):
        '''
        Submit the request, output the result and add the request to the
        request list
        :return:
        '''
        # Get the student name from the TextInputs
        requestStr = self.requestInput.text
        self.outputResult(requestStr)

        self.requestList.adapter.data.extend([requestStr])

        # Reset the ListView
        self.resetListViewScrollToEnd(self.requestList)
        self.manageStateOfRequestListButtons()
        self.requestInput.text = ''

        self.refocusOnrequestInput()

    def resetListViewScrollToEnd(self, listView):
        listView._trigger_reset_populate()
        listView.scroll_to(len(self.requestList.adapter.data) - 1)

    def manageStateOfRequestListButtons(self):
        '''
        Enable or disable history command list related controls according to
        the status of the list: filled with items or empty.
        :return:
        '''
        if len(self.requestList.adapter.data) == 0:
            # command list is empty
            self.toggleHistoButton.state = 'normal'
            self.toggleHistoButton.disabled = True
            self.replayAllButton.disabled = True
            self.requestList.height = '0dp'
        else:
            self.toggleHistoButton.disabled = False
            self.replayAllButton.disabled = False

    def outputResult(self, resultStr):
        if len(self.resultOutput.text) == 0:
            self.resultOutput.text = resultStr
        else:
            self.resultOutput.text = self.resultOutput.text + '\n' + resultStr

    def refocusOnrequestInput(self):
        # defining a delay of 0.1 sec ensure the
        # refocus works in all situations. Leaving
        # it empty (== next frame) does not work
        # when pressing a button !
        Clock.schedule_once(self.refocusTextInput, 0.1)

    def refocusTextInput(self, *args):
        self.requestInput.focus = True

    def historyItemSelected(self, instance):
        requestStr = str(instance.text)

        self.requestInput.text = requestStr
        self.refocusOnrequestInput()

    def replayAllRequests(self):
        self.outputResult('')

        for request in self.requestList.adapter.data:
            self.outputResult(request)

        self.refocusOnrequestInput()


class MySimpleGuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MySimpleGui()

    def on_pause(self):
        # Here you can save data if needed
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        # Here you can check if any data needs replacing (usually nothing)

        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbApp = MySimpleGuiApp()

    dbApp.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You add a size_hint to your root widget, so this:

```
<MySimpleGui>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    # Other Stuff
```

Becomes:

```
<MySimpleGui>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: 1, .5
```

In this case, this will take up the whole width of the screen, and half the height.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalizing on the precedent answer, I improved the settings. With the AlexAndDraw solution, my app was positioned on the bottom half of my smartphone. With the new settings, the app is positioned in the top half of the smartphone. This solution needs further refinements in order to adapt to the type of keyboard you use on your phone (I am using the outstanding [MessagEase](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exideas.mekb) keyboard).

```
<MySimpleGui>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    #optimizing app size for your smartphone with MessagEase keyboard
    size_hint: 1, .56
    pos_hint: {'x' : 0, 'y' : .44}
```

And to set the application size programmatically, add this kind of code in a method of MySimpleGui:

```
    if halfMode:
        self.size_hint_y = 0.56
        self.pos_hint = {'x': 0, 'y': 0.44}
    else:
        self.size_hint_y = 1
        self.pos_hint = {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
```